# Can a Convolutional Neural Network output images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on a deep learning problem which requires me to have a deep - learning model that has as input an image and as output another image. Now, the input and output images are of different dimensions and for this reason I cannot use an autoencoder. I have already tried to build a very simple Convolutional Neural Network that has a final output dense layer that has as "units" argument the width and height of the output image multiplied together. However, this network that I am attaching below did not have success. My questions are:

- are CNNs the right type of deep learning network to approach this problem in the way I did it?
- if not, what are the other type of deep learning networks I can experiment
  to tackle this problem?

Here is the summary of the CNN model that I have already tried:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 877, 32)       544       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 26, 877, 32)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 13, 438, 32)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 437, 16)       2064      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 12, 437, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 218, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 5, 217, 8)         520       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 5, 217, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 108, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 2, 108, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1728)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1728)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 19316)             33397364  

=================================================================
Total params: 33,400,492
Trainable params: 33,400,492
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
def generator(data_arr, batch_size = 10):

num = len(data_arr) 

if num % batch_size != 0 : 
    num = int(num/batch_size)

# Loop forever so the generator never terminates
while True: 

for offset in range(0, num, batch_size):

    batch_samples = (data_arr[offset:offset+batch_size])

    samples = []
    labels = []

    for batch_sample in batch_samples:

        samples.append(batch_sample[0])
        labels.append((np.array(batch_sample[1].flatten)).transpose())

    X_ = np.array(samples)
    Y_ = np.array(labels)

    X_ = X_[:, :, :, newaxis]

    yield (X_, Y_)

# compile and train the model using the generator function
train_generator = generator(training_data, batch_size = 10)
validation_generator = generator(val_data, batch_size = 10)

run_opts = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), input_shape = (55, 1756, 
1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(8, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(19316))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy'],
              options = run_opts)

model.summary()

batch_size = 20
nb_epoch = 6

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                    steps_per_epoch = len(training_data) ,
                    epochs = nb_epoch,
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    validation_steps = len(val_data))
```

Comment: What do you mean did not have success? You need to be very specific about the problem you are having.

Comment: Yep you are right, my CNN was not successful because the accuracy was 0. More specifically, I think this is related to the fact that my dataset is composed of 10000 images each having its specific label which is different for each sample, do you have any suggestions on why the accuracy is 0?

Comment: What is the task? Regression or classification? Your network has an odd structure, why is the softmax not at the end? Remember that accuracy is only a classification metric.

Comment: The task I have to carry out is to have a deep learning model that given an input image of dimensions 55x1756 it gives its corresponding output 11x1756 based on a dataset consisting of 10000 samples. Each of these samples has its own specific label. I was thinking of using autoencoders for this task but as it turns out the output image has to have the same dimensions of the input image. Do you have any suggestions on what type of approach I should use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it regression or classification? That depends only if the output is continuous or discrete

Comment: I would say it is a regression task

Comment: Well that's the problem, accuracy is a classification metric and it cannot be used for regression, you will always get zero accuracy if you use it for a regression task.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So CNNs are not suitable for this task or is it kust the accuracy metric that is not applicable to this case? In other words, can I still use CNNs to carry out this task?

Comment: I never said anything about CNNs, just that you cannot use accuracy in regression tasks. CNNs have been successfully used for image regression tasks

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know any image regression networks that could be adapted to this type of task? Again, you are being very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a type of [UNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597). This kind of architecture has downsampling layers, followed by up sampling layers to get back to the original spatial dimensions.

Please refer [this](https://github.com/iver56/image-regression) Image Regression article